# PHP beanstalk application giving 504 errors

Tags: php, performance, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, developer-tools

I created one webpage that select 1M records from DB tables and create a document from that. In mysqlWorkbench the process took approx 4min, but in beanstalk application with php environment it produces 504 errors. Not sure why the page getting timeout. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: You get a 504 when the Loadbalancer exceeded its timeout, which is usually between 60 and 120 seconds... in AWS you can increase this timeout to up to 10 minutes, but the 504 is inevitable if your operation takes too long and no traffic is on the wire..